# How to print avoiding two columns and setting font?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

In WPF to print a string on a printer I use the following routine:

```
public static bool PrintString(String str, string strTitle = null)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    {

        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        foreach (string line in str.Split('\n'))
        {
            Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
            myParagraph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(line));
            flowDocument.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
        }

        // Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument
        IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = flowDocument;
        printDialog.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, strTitle);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

The problem is that inexpectedly it prints on two columns and with a weird fontfamily.
I would like to print using a whole A4 sheet and to be able to change the fontfamily too. Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use A4 size printing, you have to set the ColumnWidth and PageWidth of the FlowDocument object. 
I had a same problem and I googled to get a correct width of standard A4 size.

Standard A4 has dimensions 8.27 × 11.69 inches which will be 793.92 X 1122.24 in pixels.

You can try like this.

```
FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
flowDocument.PageWidth = 793.92;
flowDocument.ColumnWidth = 793.92;
flowDocument.PageHeight = 1122.24;
```

This width is in pixels and it is for portrait orientation.

For Landscape orientation, you can use

```
FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
flowDocument.PageWidth = 1122.24;
flowDocument.ColumnWidth = 1122.24;
flowDocument.PageHeight = 793.92;
```

I am pretty sure the problem is causing due to this and this answer will resolve your problem.